# adding a multi-picklist field into my formula for my custom button

Tags: javascript, formula, custom-button

I have a custom button that has a javascript picklist that checks feild criteria. I need to add a multi-picklist field to the if statement to check if it does NOT contain "India".

**here is the if statement part:**

```
    if('{!Account.Original_Contract_Start__c}' == '' || '{!Account.Current_Contract_Start__c}' == '' || '{!Account.Contract_End__c}' == '' || '{!Account.Status__c}' != 'Active'  || {!CONTAINS(!Account.Target_Market__c, "India") == False } )
{
```

**and here's the full syntax if needed:**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")}
if('{!Account.Original_Contract_Start__c}' == '' || '{!Account.Current_Contract_Start__c}' == '' || '{!Account.Contract_End__c}' == '' || '{!Account.Status__c}' != 'Active'  || {!CONTAINS(!Account.Target_Market__c, "India") == False } )
{
window.alert("Hello {!$User.FirstName} Please make sure you have entered the values in Contract End, Original Contract Start and Current Contract Start fields and that the Account Status is Active");
}
else if('{!Account.Status__c}' == 'Active' && '{!Account.Approval_Progress__c}' == 'Closed Won')
{
window.open("/apex/echosign_dev1__AgreementTemplateProcess?masterid={!Account.Id}&templateId=a08o000000C6jYl ","_blank");
}
else if('{!Account.Status__c}' == 'Active' && '{!Account.Approval_Progress__c}' == 'Approved')
{
window.open("/apex/echosign_dev1__AgreementTemplateProcess?masterid={!Account.Id}&templateId=a08o0000004m8XH ","_blank");
}
```

Comment: Error: Field Account.Target_Market__c is a multi-select picklist field. Multi-select picklist fields are only supported in certain functions

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is [INCLUDES()](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#INCLUDES).  Change your `CONTAINS` call to `{!INCLUDES(!Account.Target_Market__c, "India") == false}`.  You can also just use `NOT()` or `!` instead of `==false` - comparing against boolean literals is generally considered bad form.  Your statement would then look like `{!NOT(INCLUDES(!Account.Target_Market__c, "India"))}` or `{!!INCLUDES(!Account.Target_Market__c, "India")}`

Comment: Thank you for the info. I actual tried both with still the same error result. any additional suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: thank you '{NOT(!INCLUDES(Account.Target_Market__c, "India"))}' works

Comment: I did a rookie move. I tested that when the conditions are not met but didn't test if it works when conditions are met, which is giving me the same result :(. but I'm closer than I was yesterday. So my popup msg comes up whether it's met or not.